# python regex: pattern not found

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern compiled as

```
pattern_strings = ['\xc2d', '\xa0', '\xe7', '\xc3\ufffdd', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc3\xa7', '\xa0\xa0', '\xc2', '\xe9']
join_pattern = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
pattern = re.compile(join_pattern)
```

and then I find pattern in file as

```
def find_pattern(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
            found = pattern.search(line)
            if found:
                print dir(found)
                logging.info('found - ' + found)
```

and my input as `path` file is

```
\xc2d 
d\xa0 
\xe7 
\xc3\ufffdd 
\xc3\ufffdd 
\xc2\xa0 
\xc3\xa7 
\xa0\xa0 
'619d813\xa03697'
```

When I run this program, nothing happens.

I it not able to catch these patterns, what is am I doing wrong here?

**Desired output**
- each line because each line has one or the other matching pattern

**Update**

After changing the regex to

```
pattern_strings = ['\\xc2d', '\\xa0', '\\xe7', '\\xc3\\ufffdd', '\\xc2\\xa0', '\\xc3\\xa7', '\\xa0\\xa0', '\\xc2', '\\xe9']
```

It is still the same, no output

**UPDATE**

after making regex to

```
pattern_strings = ['\\xc2d', '\\xa0', '\\xe7', '\\xc3\\ufffdd', '\\xc2\\xa0', '\\xc3\\xa7', '\\xa0\\xa0', '\\xc2', '\\xe9']
join_pattern = '[' + '|'.join(pattern_strings) + ']'
pattern = re.compile(join_pattern)
```

Things started to work, but partially, the patterns still not caught are for line

```
\xc2\xa0 
\xc3\xa7 
\xa0\xa0
```

for which my pattern string is `['\\xc2\\xa0', '\\xc3\\xa7', '\\xa0\\xa0']`

Comment: is it possible the \x is being escaped from in the file? in which case you need to match \\x  ?

Comment: Are you looking for literal backslashses? I agree with Joran - this looks like an escape bug.

Comment: yes I am looking for literal backslashes

Comment: use `join_pattern = "("+"|".join(pattern_strings)+")"` instead \[ \].  since [] only matches single chars ...  also you  should order your list from largest to smallest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escape the \ in the search patterns
either with `r"\xa0"` or as `"\\xa0"`

do this ....

```
 ['\\xc2d', '\\xa0', '\\xe7', '\\xc3\\ufffdd', '\\xc2\\xa0', '\\xc3\\xa7', '\\xa0\\xa0', '\\xc2', '\\xe9']
```

like everyones been saying to do except the one guy you listened too...

Answer (score 0):

Does your file actually contain `\xc2d` --- that is, five characters: a backslash followed by c, then 2, then d?  If so, your regex won't match it.  Each of your regexes will match one or two characters with certain character codes.  If you want to match the string `\xc2d` your regex needs to be `\\xc2d`.